# textarea doesn't expand to contain content

Tags: html, css

How can I make two textareas fill up a specified space dynamically. On the real page, the second textarea doesn't wrap, so it's width doesn't matter. But how can I get the box with the numbers to expand to the exact width the longest line of numbers requires?

```
#container{
  width:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
textarea{
  float:left;
  height:150px;
  font-family:monospace;
  text-align:right;
}
#t1{
  width:auto;
  min-width:10px;
  max-width:50px;
  margin-right:4px;
}
#t2{
}
```

`width:auto` doesn't seem to work. And my experimentation with `min-width` and `max-width` is also futile.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/udeLafO/1/edit)

Comment: you should post a fiddle for your problem

Comment: @Rex Had one ready, just forgot to link it >< Thanks for reminding!

Comment: Why would textareas need to do so? You seem to be using them to display data, not to request user input. Using a textarea for such purposes tends to cause problems that you would not have with `div` for example.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela This is a good thought. Would divs be able to maintain line breaks (`\n`) like a textarea? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can set `white-space: pre` in CSS.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela it's an interesting suggestion, but since there are multiple edits happening in the text edit, I don't think I can use it. Thank you though :)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need JavaScript to achieve this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `box-sizing: border-box` with percentage widths:

```
textarea {  
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Remove the specific styles for `#t1` and `#t2`, you could specify widths for each if needed, summing up to 100%.

Updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/udeLafO/19/edit